# How to remove the KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag from an opened activity on Android

Tags: android, screen

I'm opening an activity with the following flags

```
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Then later on, I want the screen to be able to time out and to turn off automatically.

I tried to remove the flag like this

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there a way to remove this flag dynamically on a displayed activity?

Comment: Try [using `setKeepScreenOn()` on a `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View?hl=en#setkeepscreenon) in that activity instead of adding flags to the window.

Comment: I tried using this to enable / disable this specific flag, while using the other flags set like in my code sample but it doesn't seem to work. The screen doesn't go to sleep after calling setKeepScreenOn(false) on a view

Answer (score 1):

Call this code:

```java
private void clearLockFlags() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```